# Sentence count that start with a specific word

Tags: python

I am trying to print a count of sentences that start with a specific word. (When, I, From as specified below). I am not getting the right sentence count.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
import re
import math

def matching_sentences(file_name, word):
    '''
    Test:
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'When')
    3 sentences begin with When
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'I')
    1 sentences begin with I
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'From')
    0 sentences begin with From
    >>>
    '''
    count = 0

    with open('bike.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if word in line.split():
               count =+ 1
            print (count," sentences begin with ", word)



# These lines are part of a larger file.
def show_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as result_file:
        print(result_file.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose = True)
```

Sample text file (bike.txt):

> When I was little I had a bike. I went everywhere on that bike! When I
> got too big for it, I gave it to my little brother. When he out grew
> it, he gave it to our sister. What did she do with it? She lost it!

Comment: is the input file correctly punctuated? you need to know the sentence delimiters..

Comment: Yes, here is the sentences from the file:

When I was little I had a bike.  I went everywhere
on that bike! When I got too big for it, I gave it to
my little brother. When he out grew it, he gave it to
our sister. What did she do with it?  She lost it!

Comment: I was told to use these delimiters with regex '\.|\?|!'

Comment: that's ok but where are you checking `if a sentence start's with the word`!!

Comment: well I guess I am not. That's where I am stuck

Comment: tell me something in the text from text file you mentioned, is every line on a new line in the text or is it like a paragraph ??

Comment: Paragraph:
```When I was little I had a bike.  I went everywhere
on that bike! When I got too big for it, I gave it to
my little brother. When he out grew it, he gave it to
our sister. What did she do with it?  She lost it!```

Comment: ok so its like a paragraph !! in your .txt file let me confirm everything appears in one line ?? please check your txt file and not output from your code !!

Comment: No, it's 4 lines, actually.

Comment: When I was little I had a bike.  I went everywhere\n
on that bike! When I got too big for it, I gave it to\n
my little brother. When he out grew it, he gave it to\n
our sister. What did she do with it?  She lost it!

Comment: that's wat i was saying it's in the line form, do you want your matching sentence function corrected or a newer better way. I will give u both w8

Comment: Whatever works better for you, I just need to make sure I use regex. But either way works for me

Comment: this guy corrected your code it should work fine, i will just put one alternate approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole content in one go and use `re.split(...)` to split it into sentences and use `.strip()` to cleanup any whitespace chars at the ends. Then just use `str.startswith(..)` to check if the sentence starts with the word or not

Here is a code to get you started:

```
import math
import re


def matching_sentences(file_name, word):
    '''
    Test:
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'When')
    3 sentences begin with When
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'I')
    1 sentences begin with I
    >>> matching_sentences('bike.txt', 'From')
    0 sentences begin with From
    >>>
    '''

    count = 0

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read().lower()
        for sentence in re.split('\.|\?|!', content):
            if sentence.strip().startswith(word.lower()):
                count += 1
        print(count, "sentences begin with", word)


# These lines are part of a larger file.
def show_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as result_file:
        print(result_file.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to python and stayed wake all night last night, you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

```py
def matching_sentences(file_name: str, word: str):
    file = Path(file_name)
    text = file.read_text()
    return sum([1 if line.split(" ")[0] == word else 0 for line in text.split("\n")])
    
print(matching_sentences("bike.txt", "When"))
## output: 3
```

Comment: This is case sensitive if word is "When" and line starts with "when" (w small) it will not count it !!

Comment: why are you doing `text.split("\n")`? can't a sentence  span multiple lines? what about multiple sentences on a single line?

Comment: @Tibebes.M well I made it clear with him, how his txt files look like. I was concerned about that too...

Comment: Also how do I make sure I check the other words in the sentence? Do I need to include them manually in the print?

Comment: you do what you were doing before use the `in` operator !